# How to decrease volume of sound effects in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: gnome, 18.04

What I am asking about:
Steps To Reproduce:

1. Increase system volume to 100%
2. Open terminal
3. Use autocompletion unsuccessfully, press TAB several times and notice annoying "water boom" that is a bit too loud.

Answer (score 2):

You can adjust the volume of system sounds in Settings - Sound: "Sound Effects" tab. Adjust the slider there to attenuate system sounds, or turn them off.

The slider on top, "output volume", is the master control. The slider "Alert volume" will adjust the volume of the system sounds relative to that of the master control.

Comment: unfortunately even the lowest level of sound effects volume is too loud